# Leap year in R some outputs are erroneous

Tags: r

Find out leap year in R

```
year <- 1990
if((year %% 4) == 0){
  if((year %% 100) == 0){
   if((year %% 400) == 0){
   print(paste(year,"is a leap year"))
}
 else{
  print(paste(year,"is a leap year"))
 }
}
 else{
   print(paste(year,"is not a leap year"))
 }
}
```

The code is fine for year 2020 or 2000. But I did not get output for year 1990.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this code?

Comment: because 1990 is not a leap year.

Comment: This is also incorrectly giving that 1700,1800 and 1900 were leap years, when they actually weren't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the logic was bit incorrect in your attempt. Also you needed another `else` at the end for the first `if`.

```
year <- 1990

if((year %% 4) == 0) {
  if((year %% 100) == 0) {
    if((year %% 400) == 0) {
      print(paste(year,"is a leap year"))
    } else {
      print(paste(year,"is not a leap year"))
    }
  } else {
     print(paste(year,"is a leap year"))
  }
} else {
  print(paste(year,"is not a leap year"))
}
```

---

You might also want to consider using `leap_year` function from `lubridate` which does this out of the box.

```
lubridate::leap_year(1990)
#[1] FALSE
lubridate::leap_year(2000)
#[1] TRUE
```

Particularly, the leap_year in the function is given by
`(year%%4 == 0) & ((year%%100 != 0) | (year%%400 == 0))`